# How to compute loss with data different from the inputs in Keras?

Tags: keras, loss-function

I'm building a model in Keras where I want to compute the loss between the outputs and data different from the inputs that are used for training.
In reality the outputs are calculated using a lambda function. Doing so, the outputs (Predicted data) are very different from the inputs.
I have a set of other data (Real data) to be compared to the outputs (Predicted data).

My model is ready to be trained but I don't know how to compute the loss between the Predicted data and my Real data (Not the inputs).

Can one help me to find a solution please ?[This is a schematic of my model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NWqv.png)

```
input_shape = (128, 128, 1)
inputs = Input(shape=input_shape, dtype=tf.float64)
x = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(5,5), strides=(1,1), padding='same', activation='relu',) (inputs)
x = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(5,5), strides=(1,1), padding='same', activation='relu') (x)
x = Dropout(0.2) (x)
x = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(5,5), strides=(1,1), padding='same', activation='relu') (x)
x = Dropout(0.2) (x)
x = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(5,5), strides=(1,1), padding='same', activation='relu') (x)
x_out = Conv2D(1, kernel_size=(5,5), strides=(1,1), padding='same', activation='softmax')(x)
y_out = Lambda(My_function) (x_out)
```